# Jquery Draggable placeholder drop over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How can I make the **placeholder element** fire an event when dragged over? I've tried making it droppable on drag start but it still doesn't fire an event.

Here's an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e70bvst1/1/).

**Html-**

```
<div class="draggable">
</div>
<div  class="draggable">
</div>
<div  class="draggable">
</div>
<div  class="draggable">
</div>
```

**CSS-**

```
.draggable{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #000;
   border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.highlight{
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px #fed700;
}
```

**JQuery-**

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
   helper: "clone",
   revert: "invalid"
}).droppable();

$(".draggable").on("dropover", function() {
   $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
$(".draggable").on("dropout", function (){
   $(this).removeClass("highlight");
});
```

When dragged over the item being dragged it doesn't change. I'm sure this is the default functionality but I'd like to display like a red X or something instead of the default nothing.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**- So I guess I made this a little confusing. So when you drag an element it leaves a placeholder behind. All I want is that placeholder to have a dropover event fire when you drag over it again.

Comment: your fiddle works great for me, drag-over works

Comment: The intent is for the placeholder of the item being dragged to fire an event. I know the other elements function normally.

Comment: which event you want?

Comment: dropover would allow me to apply styles.

Comment: Check out the edit, is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Element being dragged saved when drag start:
http://jsfiddle.net/e70bvst1/10/
EDIT, in this fiddle it's red from the start:
http://jsfiddle.net/e70bvst1/13/

```
var currentDraggedElement;
$(".draggable").draggable({
start: function(e){
    currentDraggedElement = e.target;
    $(currentDraggedElement).addClass("red");
},
stop: function(e){
    $(currentDraggedElement).removeClass("red");
},
helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
}).droppable();

$(".draggable").on("dropover", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
$(".draggable").on("dropout", function (e){
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
    currentDraggedElement = null;
});
```

hope this is really what you needed.

Comment: That adds a class to the element being dragged, not the **placeholder** element. I can add styles to that element also with the .PlaceHolder selector, but I need to know when the placeholder is dragged over to clear other classes as well.

Comment: hehe, you confused me now.. which element do you want to change the style for? the element that is being dragged (visually) or the element that is still in the same place?

Comment: The element that is still in the same place.

Comment: Well.... almost but the event still only fires when you drag over the other droppable items, not the original dragged item.

Comment: the original drag event is in the draggable `start` that's the original event

Comment: What I want is for the original item to behave like the other droppable items, so when it is dropped over, the highlight class is added the same as the others. Does that help to clarify?